# Is there a way to iterate through all Child Views of ListView and cast them to TextView

Tags: java, android, listview, drawable

Am building an app for exploring files and am using the android native resource layout for data population called `android.R.simple_list_item_1`, i have tried going through the methods of a listview to see if i can add a drawable to the left of each item in my list but didn't manage. So the only way i get to access a view from a listview is on event `OnItemClick` where the view tapped is passed as `parameter` to the method and then i can format it this way for the drawable

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//Define a listview for holding the data mined from storage
     public ListView mydata;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          //Define the listview
           mydata=findViewById(R.id.data);
           mydata.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
               //Cast view to TextView at position
                  TextView r=(TextView)view;
              //get the drawable and set to textview 
                    Drawable mydraw= ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_baseline_file_copy_24,null);
                    r.setCompoundDrawables(mydraw,null,null,null);
            }
      }
}
```

Is there in which i can get all the views in the listview, create a `loop`, `iterate` through all of them and cast to  TextView array and then set my drawable to the TextView(s)?

Comment: You need to extend ListView's ArrayAdapter and manage to call "setCompoundDrawables()" from there.

Comment: I will try to do that thanks, does array adapter got that method?

Comment: That is a TextView method. The extended Adapter is used just to inflate "android.R.simple_list_item_1" and then set its Drawable using THAT method.

Comment: Can you post an answer on the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final static class YourItemClass {
    ...
}
final static class ViewHolder {
    TextView mTextView;
    private ViewHolder(@NonNull final View simpleListItem1) {
        if (!(simpleListItem1 instanceof TextView)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("TextView was expected as root of Layout");
        this.mTextView = (TextView)simpleListItem1;
    }
}
final class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YourItemClass> {
    private final Drawable mDrawable;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    public CustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull final List<YourItemClass> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_baseline_file_copy_24,null);
        this.mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = this.mLayoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        final YourItemClass cYourItemClassAtSpecificPosition = this.getItem(position);

        holder.mTextView.setCompoundDrawables(this.mDrawable, null, null, null);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Then from your Activity/Fragment:

```
private void setItemsToListView(@NonNull final List<YourItemClass> items) {
    mListView.setAdapter(new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity(), items));
}
```

This code will run "*setCompoundDrawables()*" for each row displayed in the ListView.